# How to import knowledge articles using article import tool?

Tags: data-loader, knowledge

I need to import knowledge articles using article import tool of salesforce. I am referring this link :-
https://ap1.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_knowledge_import_cheatsheet.pdf
but I am unable to import it with zip file. I am getting error in logs as -

[MESSAGE 5/7/2015 6:51 PM] -- Import Started --
[WARNING zip:UpgradeGuide.zip - 5/7/2015 6:51 PM] The .properties file is missing.
[ERROR zip:UpgradeGuide.zip - 5/7/2015 6:51 PM] CSV file not found.
[MESSAGE 5/7/2015 6:51 PM] -- Import Failed --
Can anyone suggest, where i am going wrong? I have zip file which have .properties,.csv file and .html file.please explain the right zip file  structure.
[image: Folder structure of zip file]

Comment: can you provide a screenshot of your folder structure?

Comment: I have added screenshot of folder structure. Here guide is the html file which is used in article type's  custom field. These three files are included in one zip file which is saved on desktop. I am importing single record having "guide.html" for an article type.

Comment: It looks to me like your CSV file is not formatted correctly, can you open it in something like NotePad++ and save it again (ensure it is really a csv file). If that doesn't work, can you show us the content of the properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yipeee.... Finally i got the way. Where I was wrong , I Just directly did zip file of folder rather than selecting the three files and then making zip of it. I have different folder of all html files inside a zip file. Finally it worked :D
1.While importing of knowledge articles, be careful for the type of files (.csv or .properties). Make sure the file extension is genuinely .properties or .csv
2. give same name to .csv and .properties file 
3. Most important - select all the files (.csv,.properties and folder containing .html files) and then make zip folder of it.

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot I can't see the extensions but I will assume they have the correct extensions (.zip and .properties).

The properties file must have the same name as the CSV file. So if your CSV file is called salesforce.csv your properties file should be salesforce.properties

Answer (score 0):

First you need create a folder which contains your .csv files, then Download the .Properties file: Navigate to “Import Articles” under Setup>Data Managment>Import Articles. Select “Download Sample (TXT) for articles only.” Save the file with your HTML and .csv file.  then import then using wizard.

Comment: I tried by both the ways. But it is not working. Now, I have UpgradeGuide.html ,UpgradeGuide.csv and UpgradeGuide.properties file in one zipped folder named UpgradeGuide. But still same issue is getting.

Comment: okay go through to this link========http://opfocus.com/blog/5-steps-to-import-knowledge-articles-with-images/

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have tried again. I checked my csv file again I saved it.but it is failed again :(

Comment: CSVEncoding=UTF8
RTAEncoding=UTF8
CSVSeparator=,
#DateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd My .properties file

Comment: Yipeee.... Finally i got the way. Where i was wrong is , i Just directly did zip file  of folder rather than selecting the three files and then making zip of it. I have different folder of all html files inside a zip file.Thank you all for the replies. Finally it worked :D